# Can you define Const variables for any Class?

Tags: dart

While declaring const the following observation is not understood:

```
const abc=[3,4,5,6]
```

Here we are declaring abc as const means we are fixing pointer to point to a object. Does this mean that we cannot change list members through abc
i.e

```
abc[0]=5
```

or we cannot assign it a new list

```
abc=[5,6,7]
```

If a create a class abcd then i am not able to assign the object of this class to a const variable. Kindly update why so.

```dart
void main() {
  const a = [1, 2, 4, 5];
  a[0] = 7;
  print(a);
  const b = abcd();
}

class abcd {
  String name;
  String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`const` means the value can and will be determined at compile time and can then not be changed. For lists, `const` means you get a list which are not modifiable. Also, the variable itself pointing to the list are marked as final and can not be modified after it has been assigned a value.

Since the object itself cannot be modified, you `class` needs to define a `const` constructor and all member of the `class` should not be able to be modified after assignment which therefore require fields to marked as `final`.

So your example should be:

```
void main() {
  const b = abcd('name');
  print(b);
}

class abcd {
  final String name;

  const abcd(this.name);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

I also want to add that the `const` constructor needs be able to figure out the value at compile time. So it is rather restricted the amount of logic you can use here.

Comment: Since the const constructor needs to figure out value at compile time, we are passing value to constructor at runtime.

Comment: No, you cannot use a value which are generated at runtime. E.g. taken a input from a user. But you can still call the `const` constructor and just get a normal object from it (which are still not able to be changed after creation since all members are `final`). To guarantee that you gets a `const` instance you need to explicit write `const` as the type of the result or at the call of the constructor.